# How to run faster every time without injuries ?

Tags: running, long-distance-running

How to run faster ?

I am trying to improve my running speed... my fastest time for 400 m is 1 minute 30 seconds... 
I am trying to break this time since 1 month but I cant...

What technique I should use to run and what diet should I take to increase the energy ? 
what is the most scientific way to run ?

Comment: If you're serious about getting faster, read scienceofrunning.com and/or read the book.

Answer (score 3):

Many different possibilities.
Cross train to build up your overall athletic ability since sprinting seems from my view relies on your whole body and it will allow your muscles a break from training while still improving your cardio or other strength.

Run intervals and run further to improve speed and your base.

Train in different locations so that you are not training to stop at the finish line which may mean your slowing down before you cross it.

Use Endomondo or something similar to track your speeds so that you can focus on effort in place of time, distance, results while your running.

For sprinting I've had some help with my form by running down hill but do this at your own risk.

Look at your cadence and stride and how they compare to professionals. One way to run faster for longer distances is by focusing on a faster cadence and shorter steps because it is easier to lengthen your stride then to increase your cadence.

Thats my sum knowledge on that and I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...well, I want to concentrate on increasing my running speed right now ... is there way or techniques which improve my speed ?

Comment: @user1650894, cadence and strength training. Im almost that fast so I'm sure you can improve upon that, but you cant keep repeating your current routine if your not going anywhere. Change the routine up and do some research on the science/mechanics (like cadence) involved because alot of people have produce good material and advice on this subject. For example http://www.amazon.com/YOU-Only-Faster-Greg-McMillan/dp/1620304422 (BTW some of my advice comes from reading up on material.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what training you are currently doing, or where you are losing time?

Is it towards the end of the 400m?

Do you happen to know your 200m split?

Is this a race or during training?

If you can supply a little more information, I will try to make the answer specific to you, but with the information that I have, here is my answer.

To run a good 400m you need speed/endurance.  This means that you need to run a good speed for the whole distance, but it is too far to sprint, therefore you need some endurance as well.

What I would recommend is to train once a week, under distance. Say 200m, but do lots of them, making sure your pace is faster than that of half of the 400m.  So for you I would suggest around 40 seconds or there abouts.  Do 5-6 200 metres with no more than a minutes rest(maximum) in between.

Then in the same week I would train over distance:  3 times 600 metres or 800metres

The first session will make you faster,  the 2nd session will help you maintain pace.

A very common problem for 400m is to fade badly in the last 100m, this is caused either by lack of endurance training or starting too fast.

If you running the 400m on you own in training,you may find if you bring someone to training with you that you are able to beat your time now.  There's nothing like a bit of competition to get the best out of yourself.

Regarding technique, in the last 100m or so, when you are getting tired, concentrate on keeping your running form, make sure you are pumping your arms.  You could definitely gain a few seconds if you do that.

I hope that helps, and good luck with your goal